# How to add currency (TMT) to Commerce?

Tags: commerce

[Turkmenistan Manat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkmenistan_manat) is missing from Drupal Commerce list - how to add it to 7.x?

Answer (score 0):

Per the `commerce.api.php` file, there is a document hook which allows you to add currencies.

```
function hook_commerce_currency_info() {
  return array (
    'CHF' => array(
      'code' => 'CHF',
      'numeric_code' => '756',
      'symbol' => 'Fr.',
      'name' => t('Swiss Franc'),
      'symbol_placement' => 'before',
      'code_placement' => 'before',
      'minor_unit' => t('Rappen'),
      'major_unit' => t('Franc'),
      'rounding_step' => '0.05',
    ),
  );
}
```

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/commerce.api.php